# How to manage Javascript dependencies with Bower in Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, bower

The Javascript dependencies are growing in my Rails app and it's leading to some problems. For one, with so many it becomes difficult to track and update versions of different Javascript libraries. At first I tried [turning them into gems](http://prioritized.net/blog/gemify-assets-for-rails/), but then I have to manage those. Some are already gems (like backbone-rails) but I would like to have one consistent package manager.

So I'm looking into [Bower](http://bower.io), "a package manager for the web". Some blog posts [from kaeff](http://kaeff.net/posts/sprockets-bower-better-component-packaging-for-rails-asset-pipeline.html) and [from af83](http://dev.af83.com/2013/01/02/managing-rails-assets-with-bower.html) have been helpful, but I still run into problems. I hope this question can lead to a variety of answers people can use to find the best solution for their projects.

I'd particularly like to see advice for managing assets through Bower in a Heroku deploy.

Answer (score 27):

One way is using a version of Sprockets which allows your `application.js` to require packages defined by Bower. This feature was added in Sprockets 2.6, which Rails 3.x won't allow you to bundle [due to a version restriction](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9492). To get that feature, you can bundle `gem "sprockets", "2.2.2.backport1"`.

That will make Sprockets start looking for assets in `vendor/assets/components` too. The path is vendor/components because Bower packages could contain CSS or image assets too, not just Javascript. The way Sprockets knows what Javascript to include when you require the package is by reading the `bower.json` file for the `main` property, which says which files the pipeline should include. A gotcha here is that many Bower packages don't supply this property or supply main sources that assume RequireJS is available (e.g. [d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/component.json)). You can see what source main are defined with `bower list --map`.

When the `main` doesn't suit you, you can simply use Bower to manage a single remote JS file instead of a package. Josh Peek has [a gist that demonstrates this](https://gist.github.com/josh/3667224). The latest version of Bower expects `bower.json` instead of `component.json` so I've updated the steps:

```
$ npm install -g bower
$ mkdir -p vendor/assets
$ cd vendor/assets/
$ curl https://raw.github.com/gist/3667224/component.json > bower.json
$ bower install
```

That particular `bower.json` loads jQuery. Then in your `application.js` you can simply `//= require jquery` and Sprockets will find it in your `vendor/assets/components`. To add new dependencies, just include them in your `bower.json` and run `bower install` again, for example:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js",
    "d3": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.8/d3.js"
  }
}
```

If you want to manage your `lib` and `vendor` assets in one configuration file, you could use [bower-rails](https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails/), but there's not much point in using `lib`. That gem also provides some Rake tasks, but they don't do anything more than the basic Bower commands.

To my knowledge, there is no way yet to have Bower install as necessary during asset compilation. So if you're using a deploy environment like Heroku, you'll need to commit your `vendor/assets/components` directory and update it through the `bower` command.

It would be nice if could you require your whole Bower dependency set with one directive in `application.js`. A [gist from kaeff](https://gist.github.com/kaeff/5336060) illustrates how to create a `require_bower_dependencies` directive. There's no gem that does this for you yet. Until then, you have to declare each dependency in both `bower.json` and `application.js`.

Comment: As of 5/24/2013 sprockets bumped its version to 2.10.0, the release notes state they have added "Support for bower.json". I haven't found the documentation for it, but it's possible that there is now support for bower dependencies to be resolved during asset compilation.

Comment: EDIT: I looked at the commit, it appears that it was a change to support the convention change in bower from component.json to bower.json

Comment: "That will make Sprockets start looking for assets in vendor/assets/components too" - what about `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "components")`? Surely you shouldn't need to backport for this, or am I missing something?

Comment: chris edwards is correct - if you need [more details](http://www.synbioz.com/blog/bower)

Comment: "Sprockets knows what Javascript to include when you require the package is by reading the bower.json file for the main property..." What if you're trying to include an S/CSS or image component?

Comment: Sprockets should find CSS and image components as well. That's the advantage of Bower. (Though I have not confirmed this works.)

Comment: I had trouble getting sprockets to find the css. On a side note you don't need to specify the CDN url. You can just specify the version    "jquery": "~1.x"

Answer (score 15):

Checkout [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/) project. Usage example:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'https://rails-assets.org'

# gem 'rails-assets-BOWER_PACKAGE_NAME'
gem 'rails-assets-jquery', '~> 1.10.2'
gem 'rails-assets-sly', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'rails-assets-raphael', '~> 2.1.0'
```

UPD (26.01.2016)
Future of Rails-Assets project is on discussion. Please check [the thread](https://github.com/rails-assets/rails-assets/issues/291) and make your own decision: use it or find a workaround.

Comment: This also avoids the nodejs/npm/bower dependencies at build time, which would be introduced in using bower directly.

Answer (score 8):

Just wrote up [a guide](https://gist.github.com/afeld/5704079) for doing Rails+Bower+Heroku.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not using Heroku, but I used your config/application.rb snippet because Sprockets was choking on the source map files pulled in by Bower.  Worked a charm.

Answer (score 5):

I've been working through this issue for the last few days, and have settled on the following process.

Use the [bower-rails](https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails) gem. It provides a number of nice rake tasks that help integrate the use of bower with a rails application and the asset pipeline. I prefer to stick with the bower.json configuration instead of the ruby-based DSL that bower-rails provides. I stick with the default bower location that stores assets in vendor/assets/bower_components. Make sure to add the following to your application.rb.

```
config.assets.paths <<  Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","bower_components")
```

Once you have packages added to your bower.json, then you run the following:

```
rake bower:install
```

to install your javascript packages. You then reference the javacript in your application.js and application.css files.

As @andrew-hacking noted above rails and bower do not play nicely with javascript packages that have css and images, specifically css that references images. Bower-rails aids in fixing this issue with the provided rake task:

```
rake bower:resolve
```

It resolves relative asset paths in components by rewriting url references in component css files with the rails helper method to reference the asset in an asset pipeline friendly way. See [BowerRails::Performer#resolve_asset_paths](https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails/blob/master/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb#L118) for more detail.

My preference is to check in all of the bower_components into our repository, so we run bower:install followed by bower:resolve. You then need to add the images referenced within the package to your config.assets.precompile list for your staging and production environments. For example here is the setup for adding the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) javascript component to your rails project using bower and rails.

bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "Acme",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "select2": "3.5.1"
    }
}
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee:

```
#= require select2/select2
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass

```
//= require select2/select2
```

config/environments/staging.rb and config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ["select2/*.png",
                            "select2/*.gif"]
```

It's not perfect, but it gives you the dependency management of your javascript components, and it's better then trying to figure out what gems you need to pull in to get the desired javascript component enabled for the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else thinks using bower in your rails project is a good idea, think again.

Bower packages are simply not made to integrate with rails or sprockets.

What this means:

- they won't typically specify a manifest index.js for including your javascript via sprockets require directives.
- You will have to analyse and ferret around in the bower package and work out exactly what you need to require and from where (your require paths get kind of long)
- bower packages don't uniformly specify a main key, and even if they do the current sprockets/bower support seems to ignore them
- additional assets like fonts, images and templates won't be included in your production asset compilation (Rails 4 only includes app/assets/xxx)
- Using config.assets.precompile patterns to try and 'get around' the problem is coarse grained and will pick up lots of cruft in your bower components directories
- bower packages won't use sprocket url path helpers so any references to images and fonts within CSS/SCCS wont have the correct asset path.  Good luck with that.
- you will have to resolve all of the issues in EVERY project where you use bower packages
- `bundle install` no longer works for your projects dependencies and you have to use another package manager as well

In contrast asset gems are simple to create and provide a uniform abstraction for pulling assets into your project. You have a chance to modify the original files and use asset helpers so things work well with your rails projects. There is a decent [blog](http://prioritized.net/blog/gemify-assets-for-rails/) on creating asset gems, as well as a general [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler) on creating gems too.

IMO It would be better for the rails community to maintain up to date asset gems than every project having to deal with the issues of a bower package that was never designed to plug into the rails asset pipeline.

Comment: There are so many obscure pure-JavaScript libraries in the Bower registry that gemifying them all would be a huge amount of work; not to mention keeping the Gems up-to-date with bug fixes/features.

Comment: @brendan that may be the case, but using bower with the rails asset pipeline isn't a solution. You seem to think bower solves a problem for your rails app, well it doesn't. The only value bower provides to rails is running `git' to pull the source for you.  For that, you can use git submodules instead to pull JS from their origin repositories and avoid bower altogether.